# Chinese font displays as empty boxes

Tags: fonts, xetex, chinese

I installed a new Chinese font `Alibaba Sans Light` but I cannot get it displayed (the characters come out as empty rectangles).  My previously installed Chinese fonts are displayed OK with `xeCJK` using `XeLatex`.

I tested the font in some other software in Ubuntu Linux.  The new font is also displayed correctly.

Below I am using both `fontspec` and `xeCJK` packages.  I tried both methods individually, neither works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alibaba Sans}
\setsansfont{Alibaba Sans}
\setmonofont{Alibaba Sans}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Alibaba Sans}
\setCJKmonofont{Alibaba Sans}
\setCJKsansfont{Alibaba Sans}
\setCJKfamilyfont{alibabasans}{Alibaba Sans}

\title{人工智能}
\author{甄景贤}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

人工智能

\fontspec{Alibaba Sans} 人工智能

{\CJKfamily{alibabasans}人工智能}

\end{document}
```

Output is like this:

[image]

In the output log, the font seems to be found correctly, but with this warning:

```
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist-latn"
* 
* Font 'Alibaba Sans' does not contain script 'CJK'.
*  'Latin' script used instead.
```

I guess that's not the problem.

Comment: You must install the big files, in `阿里巴巴普惠体.zip`. The font is called `Alibaba PuHuiTi`.

Comment: “Alibaba Sans” refers to the Latin, Cyrillic and Greek parts of the project. The CJK part is in “Alibaba PuHuiTi”.

Comment: Thanks, you guys saved my life! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small font files are Latin. The big files (9 MB) are the CJK fonts.

As mentioned in the comments, the different scripts in the Ali Baba family sit well with each other.

This is Regular:

[image: Ali Baba]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Alibaba PuHuiTi}
\setmainfont{Alibaba Sans}
\title{人工智能}
\author{甄景贤}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

人工智能

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\setCJKmainfont{Alibaba PuHuiTi}` and `\setmainfont{Alibaba Sans}` to get a more uniform look?

Comment: @RuixiZhang Yes, good idea. +1